# Chrome extension: "Uncaught Error: "getBackgroundPage" can only be used in extension processes...."

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I published a chrome extension to testers only.  The app seems to work very well.  I don't see any errors when inspecting the console for the popup or the background page.  However, I get the following error when inspecting the console for any web page: "Uncaught Error: "getBackgroundPage" can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more   extensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:418"

This app contains several JavaScript files, but each one includes the code within a self executing function.  The "getBackgroundPage" calls are in the JavaScript files.

Could you please help? Isn't the app I built an isolated module independent from any web page?  How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: That error usually means your trying to use getBackgroundPage in a content script, which you cant do.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you so much for your response.  Once I removed te popup.js file from manifest.json, the error didn't replicate anymore.  However, the content now takes 30 seconds to display on popup.html.  Is there a way to make the content to display immediately?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I was trying to communicate with the background page from my content script. The correct way of doing it is via Message Passing. It is very well documented here : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html